# Convert byte data to Pytorch tensor

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, tensor, torchaudio

I created a simple model with Pytorch to recognize bird sounds and until now I feed it .wav recordings.
I want to start doing real time recognition and my question is: can I convert bytes to Pytorch tensors directly without converting it first to numpy?

What I do is make an MFCC from the audio that feed it to the model.

Thank you

What I'm doing right now is to use numpy.frombuffer and after I use torch.from_numpy as a way to convert the byte data to tensor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyTorch also has a [`torch.frombuffer`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.frombuffer.html#torch.frombuffer) function.

Answer (score 0):

there has more flexible and effcient way:

```
import numpy
import torch
resut=torch.Tensor(numpy.frombuffer(bytes_origin_var, dtype=numpy.int32))
```

where result is dtypet is numpy.int32 tensor